# Add zoom functionality on button click in android?

Tags: android, button, zooming

I am developing an application in which I swap images with finger touch and I tried to add zoom functionality on touch event but couldn't do so,now I want to have zoom functionality on images on button click 
How can i do this can you give me any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is not same as you're doing, but this guy has implemented Image Zoom feature for ImageView: http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/

Comment: Thanks for giving me response.. but unfortunately I have already used this concept. Actually I want image get zoom on button click.